# Django, Template not found

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to render this HTML File (An Home page) And I get an error that template is not found.

```py
#views.py
from django.shortcuts import render


def index(request):
    """Homepage"""
    return render(request,'templates/index.html')
```

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='Home'),
]
```

error:

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /
templates/index.html
```

and this just loads a blank page:

```py
from django.shortcuts import render


def index(request):
    """Homepage"""
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

My HTML File

I'm guessing maybe some kind of link is missing here.
I've also added 'os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"templates")' to DIRS and setting and the page is still blank.

```
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="{% url 'index' %}">Home</a>.

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Triangulation Calculator</title>
  </head>
  <body>
<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home
                <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
              </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Three Positions Triangulation</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Second </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Add Known Location</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<section class="py-5 text-center">
      <div class="container"> 
        <h2 class="text-center">Triangulation Calculator</h2>
        <p class="text-muted mb-5 text-center">There's three Features here, below, you'll find explaintion for each.</p>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 mb-3">
            <svg class="lnr text-primary services-icon">
              <use xlink:href="#lnr-magic-wand"></use>
            </svg>
            <h6>Three Positions Triangulation</h6>
            <p class="text-muted">Naming is All, Choose a grate name for your mission so you can come back and open that map whenever you want.
                You input the latitude and longitude for GDT 1, GDT 2 and the location of the UAV, also, we need the
                elevation of the uav above sea level, where do you get that data?
                Thank God for Google.
                go to google maps, when you press a location on the map you can the coordinates as we need them, in the following format:
                31.4531,35.56243.
                first is latitude and longitude, copy the values to calculator.
                done?
                press POST
                the page will refresh and you'll see all your data.
                go to the address line and add the mission name to the and of the line.
                KABLAM!
                Your map will open.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 mb-3">
            <svg class="lnr text-primary services-icon">
              <use xlink:href="#lnr-heart"></use>
            </svg>
            <h6>Second GDT options</h6>
            <p class="text-muted">Second option works a lot the same: Input your mission name and the data for GDT 1 and the UAV, and choose the area of the mission.
                and the rest is the same.
                How does the map work here?
                if you hover your mouse over one of the numbers you'll see the boundaries of that triangulation, the more you zoom in,
                the more detailed it gets.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 mb-3">
            <svg class="lnr text-primary services-icon">
              <use xlink:href="#lnr-rocket"></use>
            </svg>
            <h6>Add Location Info to the DataBase</h6>
            <p class="text-muted">Here you input a base,outpost,mountain or just every location you ever put a GDT in.
                choose the area where that position lies.
                and every time someone will use the second option, we'll automatically add those positions to the map.</p>
          </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</section>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your second approach is correct. Please post your index.html to check why it is blank

Comment: Did you write content in index.html?

Comment: What directory does `index.html` exist in?

Comment: app/templates/index.html

Comment: Why do you have html **before** `<!doctype html>`?  This should always be first on the page.

Comment: @ReinstateMonica changed that, still a blank page.

Comment: In my case, I forgot to add my new apps into INSTALLED_APPS. If you store the template inside the app like new_app/templates, don't forget to add new_apps to the INSTALLED_APPS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create templates folder on same level of app not in the app, and set `TEMPLATES` variable in `settings.py`

**settings.py**

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Now, you can add `index.html` in templates folder or you can add `index.html` file in an appropriate folder and add that folder in the templates folder. Folder structure is like below...

```
 app_1
   |
   |
 app_2
   |
   |
templates
   |
   |__index.html
```

Comment: This was my original thought, and I almost posted this as an answer, but I doubt it is the solution.  If it were the solution, OP would be getting `TemplateDoesNotExist` error instead of a blank page.

Answer (score 2):

Check whether you have added the template_dir, if not add this in your settings.py below the BASE_DIR

```
TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')
```

and find templates and dirs as a dictionary file in the settings.py, add this

```
DIRS = [TEMPLATE_DIR,]
```

or directly you can add in DIRS like this

```
DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')]
```

and make sure the directory name is templates not template according to my answer

Comment: Added that, by still a blank page.

Comment: check the directory name and file name..if you add the settings.py and file directory hierarchy we could you i guess. or else try with creating another simple html file and check whether it is working or not